# Why do we add this code when using mmap in Google Maps API?

Tags: python, maps

```
net, cid, lac = 404415, 40962, 128
import urllib

# net = MCC 404 & MNC 415

a = '000E00000000000000000000000000001B0000000000000000000000030000'
b =hex(cid)[2:].zfill(8) + hex(lac)[2:].zfill(8)
c = hex(divmod(net,100)[1])[2:].zfill(8) + hex(divmod(net,100)[0])[2:].zfill(8)
string = (a + b + c+ 'FFFFFFFF00000000').decode('hex')

try:
    data = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/glm/mmap',string)
    r = data.read().encode('hex')
    if len(r) > 14:
          print float(int(r[14:22],16))/1000000, float(int(r[22:30],16))/1000000
    else:
          print 'no data in google'
except:   
            print 'connect error'
```

I need to understand why we need to send this specific format to mmap . Especially regarding the

```
a = '000E00000000000000000000000000001B0000000000000000000000030000'
```

and why add 'FFFFFFFF00000000' to the string. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the google maps API documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a *guess*.

But i'm assuming the a = '...' is the location string and the FFFFFF0000000 is just a padding at the end to tell the API that this is the end of your request?

And the reason to why the "a" string looks so odd is most likely because google maps supports a hughe bunch of things such as Streetview, Google Places, pictures etc. So in the core, that's just longitude and latitude but with a bunch of extra stuff on it.

So yea, that's just Longitude and Latitude.
And the rest is just padding.

Net, Cid and Lac are GPS specific values, i think it's Cid that's the ID of you (short for CallerID) and the Lac are the local area code so you're probably doing something for the android?

- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/
- http://eng.xakep.ru/link/50814/
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/
- http://www.cellumap.com/map.html

Comment: The above code returns lat and long info as a response from google.  print float(int(r[14:22],16))/1000000, float(int(r[22:30],16))/1000000 . So I dont think information in a is lat long.